# Python module is imported on terminal but not on IDLE

Tags: python, import, module, pynput

I use python 3.6.4 and my OS is macOS High Sierra.

So I've installed `pynput`. I can import it well on terminal, however, not on Python IDLE.
[image]

I've used `sys.version` & `sys.path` and they're the same. I only have python 3.6 installed on my Mac
[image]

Does anyone know the reason why and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have multiple versions of python installed.
Use this line of code in both IDLE and Terminal:

`import sys
sys.version
sys.path`

You will get system PATH of your current python. Now just delete one of them and that's it.

Comment: sys.version
'3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'

Comment: sys.path
['', '/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa']

Comment: These two are from the terminal, I guess they're the same?

Comment: Yea, I see. Maybe the problem is what @Stavros Avrimidis said.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on the terminal you use Anaconda which is unknown to IDLE.
You can use Spyder which comes with Anaconda

Edit: You'll find IDLE from: c:\Anaconda\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat 
On mac i think you should do this `pip install spyder`

Comment: what is it and how to use it? (Sorry I'm a newbie)

Comment: The reason I need to use IDLE is because I'm also using openCV which requires to use IDLE when activating the camera

Comment: You'll find IDLE from: c:\Anaconda\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat

Comment: Also you could simple install `pynput` in the normal python enviroment

Comment: sorry didn't get what you mean for "c:\Anaconda\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat"

and how do I install pynput in normal python environment? I used pip install before

Comment: This is the location of Spyder Anaconda's IDLE

Comment: Oh, sorry you are on MAC

Comment: I think this is needed `pip install spyder`

Comment: I have it in anaconda it says

Comment: It should be availlable via search then

Comment: and what should I do next so I can use pynput module on IDLE?

Comment: In order to use it on the normal IDLE you should install the module on normal python. I don't know how you can enter the normal ptyhno env. on mac but you can try typoing the full path `usr/bin/python/`